# Either PyPi Wheel Package fails or source code fails to import a bundled python file

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

1. If I import a module with
   "from diskspace_report.pkg_helpers import config_report" the PyPi.org wheel package works, but the source code fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diskspace_report.pkg_helpers'; 'diskspace_report' is not a package"
2. If I import a module with "from pkg_helpers import config_report" the source code works, but not the pyPi.org wheel package.

I build the package with python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel (python2).
If I build with "python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel" I get the following errors:

https://pypi.org/project/diskspace-report/
See the source code for the working soucecode on GitHub:https://github.com/apaeffgen/diskspace_report

---

Fixed it with the following import statement:

```
try:
    from  diskspace_report.pkg_helpers import config_report
except ImportError:
    error_log()
try:
    from pkg_helpers import config_report
```

Comment: pip show --files list all of the necessary files.
Tried different things first.

Comment: You could try import sys and print(sys.path) which prints directories Python searches for modules. Check if the directory its in is there. If you can add more context, the error output could be helpful

Comment: Do you have a complete stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: It's either `import .config_report` (explicit relative import) or `import diskspace_report.config_report` (absolute import) but not  `import config_report` because there is no global module or package  `config_report` available for absolute import. Implicit relative import was working in Python 2 but it no longer works in Python 3.

Comment: I belief this is not a duplicate. But you will find the answer above in the question